# GET request from JQuery to Python Flask

Tags: jquery, python, json, http, flask

I'm looking for making a GET request from a JQuery basic script in a HTML page, to a Python script with Flask.

My stuff (on the same local network) :

- a RaspberryPi 2B+ with Python 2.7, a virtualenv for Flask used as a Web server (apache2)
- a Windows PC with Firefox 55.0.3 as a Web client

I can do my request on the local machine with cURL like this :

[image: screen of the cURL command line request to Flask]

Here is my basic script in Python to treat the request :

```
#!flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import MySQLdb
from pprint import pprint

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

@app.route('/get_configuration', methods=['GET'])
def get_configuration():
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="user", passwd="pass", db="db")
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT mode, threshold FROM configuration;")
    res = cur.fetchall()
    tab = res[0]
    db.close()
    return jsonify(mode=tab[0], threshold=tab[1])

# [...]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

And here is my Web page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
           url : 'http://192.168.1.21:5000/get_configuration',
           type : 'GET',
           dataType : 'json',
           success : function(code_html, statu){
            alert("ok");
           },
           error : function(result, status, error){
            alert("error");
           },
           complete : function(result, status){
            alert("complete");
           }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<button>Get External Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT** : My Web page is currently hosted on a WampServer on Windows PC for dev&test, not yet on the RapsberryPi, so not next to Flask.

So, when I launch my web page, here is the result :

[image: Request to Flask via JQuery]

The request seems good, but the response indicates a SyntaxError : JSON.parse...

Firstly, I didn't managed to solve this problem.
But, amazingly, when I execute this request via the Firefox Dev tool like here down, it works ! We can see JSON data in response.

[image: Request to Flask with FFDevTool]

I don't know why it does work with the FF Dev Tool, and not with the JQuery example. 
I noticed that FF Dev Tool added 2 more options in the header (for no-caching), I added it to my JQuery request, but this is not the cause.
Can someone help me ?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: It looks like a cross domain problem. Where is your web page hosted? Is it hosted on `http://192.168.1.21:5000`?

Comment: My Web page is not yet on the RPi (192.168.1.21), it's on my Web client (for the development), on the same local network.

Comment: Please deploy your web page on 192.168.1.21 and try again. Ajax request is restricted by same origin policy, while HTTP request sent from software (e.g. Firefox Dev Tool) isn't.

Comment: I just tried, the Web page is now hosted on the RPi, and I call it again from the Windows PC throught the network. But it doesn't change anything, I have again an error with the JQuery request ("SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"), and FF Dev Tool gives me the expected response with my JSON data.

Comment: Interesting, can you remove `dataType : 'json'` and check what is the response in jQuery request?

Comment: I just tried to put "dataType : 'text'", then I deleted this line, both give the same result. 
I also downloaded JQuery library file to provide it directly on the RPi, no more changes.

Comment: hmmm... Sorry @Rasta 29 but I can't find any other suspicious clue... After deploy webpage on server and remove JSON restriction, it is a pretty simple Ajax request and should not lead to problem...

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your help ! :)